# Unable to access assets from an array through hyperledger rest server

Tags: rest, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to access an asset inside an array from another asset though hyperledger rest api .

a part of my .cto looks like this :

```
asset AirSpaceZones identified by Id {
  o String Id 
  --> zone [] reqZones
  --> CTAzone [] CTA

}


abstract asset zone identified by Id {
  o String Id
  o String zoneName

}

asset CTAzone extends zone {
  o String upperLimit
  o String lowerLimit 
  o String type 
  o String zoneClass

}
```

my Api call looks like this : 
http://localhost:3000/api/AirSpaceZones/PermanentAirspace

the response is :

```
$class  "org.example.nz.AirSpaceZones"
Id  "PermanentAirspace"
reqZones    
0   "resource:org.example.nz.CTAzone#NZA131"
1   "resource:org.example.nz.FIRzone#NZZC"
CTA 
0   "resource:org.example.nz.CTAzone#NZA131"
```

I need the api call to be like 
http://localhost:3000/api/AirSpaceZones/PermanentAirspace/CTA/NZA131

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is defining relations for models , the hyperledger rests server uses loopback connectors so :

1. create a loopback connector app against your running business network 
   refer : https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/customizing-the-rest-server
2. Define relations , refer  : https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-model-relations.html